# Moving from EDU to java.util.concurrent cuts the performance twice

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Cross post from http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2195025&tstart=0

There is a telecom application server (JAIN SLEE based) and the application running in it.
The application is receiving a message from the network, processes it and sends back to the network a response.
The requirement for request/response latency is 250 ms for 95% of calls and 3000 ms for 99.999% of calls.
We use EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, 1 instance. For one call (one call is several messages) processing the following methods are invoked:

```
"put", "get", "get", "get", then in 180 seconds "remove".
```

There are 4 threads which invoke these methods.
(A small note: working with ConcurrentHashMap is not the only activity. Also for one network message there are a lot of other activities: protocol message parsing, querying a DB, writing an SDR into a file, creating short living and long living objects.)

When we move from EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, we see a performance degradation from 1400 to 800 calls per second.
The first bottleneck for the last 800 calls per second is not sufficient latency for the requirement above.

This performance degradation is reproduced on hosts with the following CPU:

- 2 CPU x Quad-Core AMD Opteron 2356
  2312 MHz, 8 HW threads in total,
- 2 CPU x Intel Xeon E5410 2.33 GHz, 8
  HW threads in total.

It is not reproduced on X5570 CPU (Intel Xeon Nehalem X5570 2.93 GHz, 16 HW threads in total).

Did anybody face similar issues? How to solve them?

Comment: Interesting, but do you *need* to move to `java.util.concurrent`? Even if the two libraries have the same origin, they have drifted apart, and the oswego library may well have incorporated performance improvements since then.

Comment: Is this a real question?  It seems more like an observation followed by an invitation to "share experiences".  (It IS an interesting observation though!)

Comment: @skaffman We are obliged to move from EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent because of the license issues. BTW the origin of these libraries is not the same: EDU is based on classic synchronized; java.util.concurrent is based on CompareAndSwap instructions.

Comment: what did you see when you profiled the application?

Comment: @Stephen C The real question is actually how to solve this problem. What could be the root of this problem.

Comment: @jtahlborn I didn't notice any difference in profiling EDU and java.util.concurrent. We also measured the time of execution of methods "put", "get", "remove" and collected the statistics min/max/average. No difference was observed. Max time was comparable with maximum stop-the-world pause in gc.log (280 milliseconds).

Comment: @Neighbour - did you just do simple timings, or did you profile the live application with an actual profiler?

Comment: @Neighbour: Can you describe distribution of `Map` keys? Also, if you can't see any changes in timings of `Map` methods, have you tried to identify the source of slowdown?

Comment: @axtavt: The distribution of Map keys is Integer, incremented by 1.

Comment: @Neighbour - one more question - when you say '"put", "get", "get", "get", then in 180 seconds "remove"'. Do you mean that you "put" once, and then "get" the same value from different places in code a few times, or are you issuing "get" to get different values.

Comment: @bartosz.r put, get, get, get, remove - is the set of operations performed on the same key for one call (which consists of 5 different incoming network messages). So we have one map operation per each network message.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are taking about nano-seconds rather than milli-seconds. (That is one million times smaller!)

**OR** the use of ConcurrentHashMap is a trivial portion of your delay.

EDIT: Have edited the example to be multi-threaded using 100 tasks.

```
/*
Average operation time for a map of 10,000,000 was 48 ns
Average operation time for a map of 5,000,000 was 51 ns
Average operation time for a map of 2,500,000 was 48 ns
Average operation time for a map of 1,250,000 was 46 ns
Average operation time for a map of 625,000 was 45 ns
Average operation time for a map of 312,500 was 44 ns
Average operation time for a map of 156,200 was 38 ns
Average operation time for a map of 78,100 was 34 ns
Average operation time for a map of 39,000 was 35 ns
Average operation time for a map of 19,500 was 37 ns
 */
 public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    try {
        for (int size = 100000; size >= 100; size /= 2)
            test(es, size);
    } finally {
        es.shutdown();
    }
}

private static void test(ExecutorService es, final int size) {
    int tasks = 100;
    final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>(tasks*size);
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int j = 0; j < tasks; j++) {
        final int offset = j * size;
        futures.add(es.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    map.put(offset + i, "" + i);
                int total = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        total += map.get(offset + i).length();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    map.remove(offset + i);
            }
        }));
    }
    try {
        for (Future future : futures)
            future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Average operation time for a map of %,d was %,d ns%n", size * tasks, time / tasks / 12 / size);
}
```

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Of course working only with ConcurrentHashMap in one thread will provide great throughput with nanoseconds latency. As I said, working with ConcurrentHashMap is not the only activity. Also for one network message there are a lot of other activities: protocol message parsing, querying a DB, writing an SDR into a file, creating short living and long living objects. Considering all these activities, overall request/response latency will be measured in milliseconds, sometimes in seconds.

Comment: And I would say it has nothing to do with CHM. A single IO access will be many times greater.

Comment: But nothing else was changed. Only that CHM. And after that the latency becomes a disaster.

Comment: I have edited the example to be multi-threaded and this reduced the delay to 55 ns.  This is not going to make a millis-second difference unless its called 10,000 times or more. There must be other things which have changed in your system which you are not aware of.  Have you tried profiling the system to see where it is spending the time.

Comment: Can we ask OP to profile `Peter Lawrey's ConcurrentHashMap code` above using oswego library? With the same test code, we can objectively compare the libraries first. If they are different in performance, then we can say it is a library problem. If they are more or less the same, then it could be something else...

Comment: @Peter Lawrey We developed a temp version of a component which changes behavior depending on System property: 
`       
        String mapType = System.getProperty( "map-type", "concurrent" );
        if( "concurrent".equals( mapType ) ) {
            map = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, byte[]>();
        }
        else {
            map = new EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap();
        }
`
So I'm confident, this is the only change.
I profiled the system under VisualVM,JProfiler and YourKit.
All HotSpots are in different places, not in CHP invocations.

Comment: Running the same test with the ConcurrentHashMap downloaded from oswedo, the timing dropped to 22 ns.  You would still need to be calling this Map millions of times to make a difference of 100 ms. If this is the case, I suggest you refactor your code so you are calling this Map only a few thousand times or much less.

Comment: @eee I ran the simple test where only ConcurrentHashMap of EDU and SUN were tested. The test showed almost the same performance. It seems like the root of my problem is in interconnection between ConcurrentHashMap and other activities of an application.

Comment: This test case uses computed offset as a key, and that offset is beautifully distributed between locks in the map (At least this is what I understand after first look at the code). Try this test with something different. I don't know if random would be any good. I can repeat what I said again, the key to the performance of the CMS is the hashcode of the KEY. @Neighbour can you tell us what is the policy for generating key's and maybe hashcodes for your keys? Is it the same way as in this test - because I think it is not.

Comment: @bartosz.r The key is an Integer, incremented by 1 for each new value.

Comment: @Neighbour then I suppose the default hashCode for integer should give you the good spread of values in the ConcurrentHashMap, I think that EDU..CMS is just the tool that best suites your needs.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, @Neighbour I did this test, but I have used one global incremented Integer as a key, and on my machine (only DualCore) there is no difference. As a second test I have run the version with the offset as used here, no difference. So it says me that the hashCode for integer is very good. And I think the synchronization used may be Hardware dependent, whether this is something with only real-cores, or with HT and so on.

Comment: @bartosz.r, the important thing it the distribution of hashCode values. If you use continous integer the distribution is even.

Answer (score 1):

At first, did you check that the hash map is indeed the culprit? Assuming, that you did: There is a [lock-free hash map](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/) designed to scale to hundreds of processors without introducing alot of contention. It's authored by Cliff Click a well known engineer on the original Hot Spot compiler team. Now, working on scaling the JDK to machines with hundreds of CPUs. So, I assume that he knows what he is doing in that hash map implementation. More infos about this hash map can be found in these [slides](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2007/2007_LockFreeHash.pdf).

Comment: That is a good idea. I've tested this high-scale-lib, it's pity, but the result is the same - 800 CPS with high-scale-lib lib, 1400 CPS with EDU library.

Comment: @Neighbour: On what kind of operating system does your server run? If it is solaris, then you could use dtrace for lightweight monitoring and inspection of contention. Did you try tweak the parallelization of the ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Yes, it is Solaris. Good idea, I will try dtrace, though it will take a while... But I can say that we added in the code measurement of min/max/average time spent in operations "put", "get", "remove". Maximum time spent in them was about 200 ms, which was comparable with maximum stop-the-world pause in gc.log. On the other hand, we have calls that are above 3 seconds. Also we tried different concurrency levels with the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing th **concurrencyLevel** in the ConcurrentHashMap? Try some lower values like 8, try some bigger values. And remember that the performance and concurrency of ConcurrentHashMap is **dependend on you quality of HashCode** function.

And yes, it - the java.util.ConcurrentHashMap has the same origin (Doug Lee from edu.oswego) as edu.oswego.cs.dl... , but it was totally rewritten by him so it can better scale.

I think it may be good for you to checkout the javolution fast map. It may be better suited for real-time applications.

Comment: I tried concurrencyLevel 4, 32, 64. The result is the same bad. Probably instead of trying new implementations of CHM we will stay with EDU library and will try to solve license issues.

Comment: What kind of licence issues? I think (I can be 100% sure) that you can use the EDU jars in commercial products. Even CMS which uses part of Java implementation (the same way you can use java). Look at the FAQ written by Doug Lea: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html.

Comment: I don't know the details. This is just the information from our Legal department.